# Converting an OpenCV Mat of complex floats to grayscale

Tags: c++, opencv

I am reading in the first frame of a video from a file using OpenCV and storing it into a `Mat_<std::complex<float> >` and trying to convert it to grayscale using the following code:

```
cv::VideoCapture capture("test.mp4");

cv::Mat_<std::complex<float> > first_frame;

capture >> first_frame;

try {
    cv::cvtColor(first_frame, first_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
} catch (cv::Exception &e) {
    std::cout << "failed in converting colour\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The code in the `try` block, however, throws an Exception with message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in create, file C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, 
line 2130 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' 
what():  C:\...\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:2130: error: (-215) !fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype in function create
```

I am not sure why the code is throwing this exception. I have seen this error message before and that time it was because I was trying to output to an array of a different type than the input, but this isn't the problem this time (I don't think).

Do I need to use a different constant in the `cvtColor` function?

Comment: There a  few thing that seems wrong. 1) `cv::Mat_<std::complex<float>>` is a 2 channel matrix (you can check that using `first_frame.channels()` before the capture). So it can't be used in `convertTo(..., COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, since it expects a 3 channel matrix. 2) I don't think that you're grabbing the video correctly, Can you chech a) the return value of the capture: `bool ret =capture.read(first_frame);`, and 2) check the type of `first_frame` after the grab?

Comment: 3) What's the rationale behind converting a 2 channel matrix (of type std::complex) into a 1 channel matrix (gray)? What the gray value should be? The magnitude of the complex number, maybe?

Comment: `cv::Mat_<std::complex<float> >` - that's a terrible idea. use a plain cv::Mat instead

Comment: just curious, what is the motivation behind 
cv::Mat_<std::complex<float> >?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi the motivation behind it is so that I can work out the complex conjugate of the matrix later on. I followed the guidance of this post http://answers.opencv.org/question/23257/complex-conjugate/.

Comment: @berak Can I use that type to calculate the complex conjugate? That was the reason for using `cv::Mat_<std::complex<float> >`

Comment: @Miki The return value from doing `capture.read` is `1` and the type is `16`.

Comment: 16 means that your image is of type `CV_8UC3`.

Comment: To sum up: 1) read the image with the proper type (CV_8UC3). 2) Convert to gray (CV_8UC1). 3) Eventually your float or complex matrices. Don't mix up matrices that represent images and matrices that represents some computation result

Comment: I saw that post. I think you have just to load your mat as usual then convert it to complex space